# What are the COM components of Excel?

Tags: wpf, com

I am writing a C# WPF app that open, close, read and write to Excel.

I am curious when we say we use COM to manipulate Excel, what are the COM components we are talking about?

Does, for example, a WorkBook or a a WorkSheet is one of the COM component just like a TextBox is .NET Control components?

Also, before a Macro is run on an Excel sheet, a security warning would mentioned ActiveX. Does Excel consists of both COM components and ActiveX components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel itself is the COM component, it implements an out-of-process COM server.  WorkBook and WorkSheet are coclasses implemented by the server.  ActiveX was a marketing name for COM components, fallen out of favor since their debacle with security issues in Internet Explorer.  Excel itself can use COM servers (ActiveX components) too, that's what the warning is about.

Comment: So COM is a library of classes and properties for Excel to use? Do we install COM component when we install Windows or Office?

Comment: COM is a technology, similar to .NET.  It was its predecessor.  Yes, Windows comes with lots of COM servers pre-installed.  Look in the COM tab of the Project + Add Reference dialog.  That's COM Automation, a sub-set of COM.